# Map function using if statement

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Here is what I tried (that doesn't work), reduced at minimum terms

```
uti[{z1_, z2_}] = z1^(1/3)*z2^(2/3)
fro[a_, b_] = 
If[a < b, {{a, b}, {2*a, b}, {3 a, b}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
uf[a_, b_] = Map[uti, fro[a, b]]
uf[2,3]
```

what I want to accomplish is the following (which works, but in more complex example is a mess). Somehow Map is not liking the if statement at the function level.

```
fro1[a_, b_] = {{a, b}, {2*a, b}, {3 a, b}}
fro2[a_, b_] = {{0, b}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
ufro[aa_, bb_] = 
If[aa < bb, Map[uti, fro1[aa, bb]], Map[uti, fro2[aa, bb]]]
ufro[2,3]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In both cases you should use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) for your function definitions, e.g.

```
uti[{z1_, z2_}] := z1^(1/3)*z2^(2/3)
fro[a_, b_] := 
 If[a < b, {{a, b}, {2*a, b}, {3 a, b}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
uf[a_, b_] := Map[uti, fro[a, b]]
uf[2, 3]
```

> {2^(1/3) 3^(2/3), 6^(2/3), 3 2^(1/3)}